# Rails 3 - Time zone dropdown with only US zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, timezone

I know there is this

```
<%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones %>
```

but it returns all timezones but has the US on the top.  I only want the US ones and I can't seem to figure out if there is a way to use this with select_tag or collection_select without me building my own hash.  Very interested in knowing.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<%= f.collection_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones, :name, :to_s %>
```

Comment: idlefingers...your the bomb.  I tried everything last night at 3:00am and just couldn't get this to work.  Works like a dream :)